# Optimizing EF flattening

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a similar case to the following:
Say there's a number of jobs to be done and for each job there's a history of workers where only one worker is active per job. There's three tables: the Job itself, a mapping table JobWorkers which holds the history of workers for a given job (including a datetime "To" which indicates whether still active (null) or when assignment was cancelled (end date)) and Workers which have a first and last name.
I'd like to query a list of all jobs and the first and last name of the currently assigned worker **as flat model**. This is the code I'm executing:

```
var jobExample = dbContext.Jobs.Select(j => new
{
    j.JobId,
    // ...some other columns from jobs table
    j.JobWorker.FirstOrDefault(jw => jw.To == null).Worker.FirstName, // first name of currently assigned worker
    j.JobWorker.FirstOrDefault(jw => jw.To == null).Worker.LastName // last name of currently assigned worker
}).First();
```

The following SQL query is generated:

```
    SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[JobId] AS [JobId], 
    [Extent3].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent5].[LastName] AS [LastName]
    FROM     [tables].[Jobs] AS [Extent1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent2].[WorkerId] AS [WorkerId]
        FROM [tables].[JobWorkers] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[JobId] = [Extent2].[JobId]) AND ([Extent2].[To] IS NULL) ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tables].[Workers] AS [Extent3] ON [Limit1].[WorkerId] = [Extent3].[WorkerId]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent4].[WorkerId] AS [WorkerId]
        FROM [tables].[JobWorkers] AS [Extent4]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[JobId] = [Extent4].[JobId]) AND ([Extent4].[To] IS NULL) ) AS [Limit2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tables].[Workers] AS [Extent5] ON [Limit2].[WorkerId] = [Extent5].[WorkerId]
```

As one can see there're two outer apply/left outer joins that are identical. I'd like to get rid of one of those to make the query more performant. 
Note that the select statement is dynamically generated based on what information the user actually wants to query. But even if this didn't apply I'm not sure how to do this without having a hierarchic structure and then only afterwards flatten it in .NET

Thanks for your help and if I can improve this question in any way please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably seen that there are two types of LINQ methods: the ones that return `IQueryable<...>`, and the other ones.

Methods of the first group use deferred execution. This means, that the query is made, but not executed yet. Your database is not contacted.

Methods of the second group, like ToList(), FirstOrDefault(), Count(), Any(), will execute the query: they will contact the database, and fetch the data that is needed to calculate the result.

This is the reason, that you should try to postpone any method of the second group to as last as possible. If you do it earlier, and you do something LINQy after it, changes are that you fetch to much data, or, as in your case: that you do execute the same code twice.

The solution is: move your FirstOrDefault to a later moment.

```
var jobExample = dbContext.Jobs.Select(job => new
{
    Id = job.JobId,
    ... // other job properties

    ActiveWorker = job.JobWorkers
        .Where(jobWorker => jobWorker.To == null)
        .Select(worker => new
        {
            FirstName = worker.FirstName,
            LastName = worker.LastName,
        })
        .FirstOrDefault(),
})
.FirstOrDefault();
```

The result is slightly different than yours:

```
Id = 10;
... // other Job properties

// the current active worker:
ActiveWorker =
{
     FirstName = "John",
     LastName = "Doe",
}
```

If you really want an object with Id / FirstName / LastName, add an extra Select before your final FirstOrDefault:

```
.Select(jobWithActiveWorker => new
{
    Id = jobWithActiveWorker.Id,
    ...  // other Job properties

    // properties of the current active worker
    FirstName = jobWithActiveWorker.FirstName,
    LastName = jobWithActiveWorker.LastName,
})
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Personally I think that you should not mix Job properties with Worker properties, so I think the first solution: "Job with its currently active worker" is neater: the Job properties are separated from the Worker properties. You can see why that is important if you also wanted the Id of the active worker:

```
.Select(job => new
{
    Id = job.JobId,
    ... // other job properties

    ActiveWorker = job.JobWorkers
        .Where(jobWorker => jobWorker.To == null)
        .Select(jobworker => new
        {
            Id = jobworker.Id,
            FirstName = jobworker.FirstName,
            LastName = jobworker.LastName,
        })
        .FirstOrDefault(),
})
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The reason why it is done by that is because this is how it will be displayed on the frontend: A table of all jobs and their data + who is currently working on them. The example is slightly simplified and it is made sure that there can be no naming overlap.

So as expected I need some intermediate format

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your query like this:

```
var query =
    from j in dbContext.Jobs
    let ws = j.JobWorker
        .Where(jw => jw.To == null)
        .Select(jw => jw.Worker)
        .Take(1)
    from w in ws.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        j.JobId,
        // other properties
        w.FirstName,
        w.LastName,
    };
```

The query processor probably could not have optimized any further to know it could use the subquery once.